# ViewPager Fragments doesn't show correct data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i'm pretty new with Fragments and ViewPager. I'm using ActionBarSherlock and ViewPageIndicator  from Jack Wharton.

I've started with a standard Android MasterDetailFlow Activity and did try to modify it to use a ViewPager in the detail part.

I'm using the standard DummyContent to provide some static data but i've replaced the DummyItem with my "Survey"-Library i have to use in this app. DummyContent provides a public static ArrayList which i use to fill the list in the list activity. After i choose a survey in this list, the corresponding questions should be shown in the view pager.

Here is the code of my QuestionActivity.java which hosts the question fragments.

```
    public class QuestionActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private QuestionsFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private PageIndicator mIndicator;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    private String surveyName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_viewpager);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        surveyName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_SURVEY_NAME);

        mAdapter = new QuestionsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), DummyContent.mgr.getSurvey(surveyName).getQuestions());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (PageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }
}
```

QuestionsFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
public class QuestionsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Question> questions;

    public QuestionsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Question> questions) {
        super(fm);

        this.questions = (ArrayList<Question>) questions;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment f = QuestionFragment.newInstance(questions.get(position));
        return  f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questions.size();
    }
}
```

QuestionFragment.java

```
public class QuestionFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    protected enum QuestionType {
        FT, SC, MC;
    }

    public final static String ARG_QUESTION_QUESTION = "question_question";
    public final static String ARG_QUESTION_TYPE = "question_type";
    public final static String ARG_QUESTION_ANSWERINGOPTIONS = "question_answeringptions";

    private TextView lblQuestion;
    private EditText txtAnswer;
    private ListView listAnswers;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    private Question question;
    private int listLayout;

    /**
     * 
     * @param question
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionFragment newInstance(Question question) {

        QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();

        // Creates a Bundle with all informations available in the question obj.
        Bundle args = createBundleFromQuestion(question);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Creates the question object from the given arguments.
        // I know this isn't a good solution, i will implement the
        // Parcelable asap i have solved the current issues.
        // 
        createQuestionFromBundle(getArguments());

//      String questionXml = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(ARG_QUESTION_XML) : null;
//      this.question = (Question) MyXmlSerializer.deserialize(questionXml, Question.class);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a the Question object form the Bundle.
     * @param extras
     */
    private void createQuestionFromBundle(Bundle extras) {
        // Think we don't need it here. The field question gets instantiated.
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_question, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initWidgets();
        setCorrectLayout();
        initContent();
    }

    private void initContent() {
        String questionStr = question.getQuestion();
        lblQuestion.setText(questionStr);

        if(question instanceof FTQuestion) {

        } else if (question instanceof ClosedQuestion) {

            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), listLayout);

            List<Answer> answeringOptions = question.getAnswers();
            for(Answer answer : answeringOptions) {
                listAdapter.add(answer.getAnswer());
            }

            listAnswers.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void initWidgets() {
        listAnswers = getListView();
        lblQuestion = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lblQuestion);
        txtAnswer = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the FT/SC/MC layout
     */
    private void setCorrectLayout() {
        if(question instanceof FTQuestion) {
            setFtLayout();
        } else if (question instanceof SCQuestion) {
            setScLayout();
        } else if (question instanceof MCQuestion) {
            setMcLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void setFtLayout() {
        if(listAnswers.getVisibility()!=ListView.INVISIBLE && listAnswers.getVisibility()!=ListView.GONE) {
            listAnswers.setVisibility(ListView.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void setScLayout() {
        listLayout = R.layout.answer_question_single_choice_list_row;
        listAnswers.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        if(txtAnswer.getVisibility() == TextView.VISIBLE) txtAnswer.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void setMcLayout() {
        listLayout = R.layout.answer_question_multiple_choice_list_row;
        listAnswers.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        if(txtAnswer.getVisibility() == TextView.VISIBLE) txtAnswer.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }
}
```

Choosing the right survey in the list works fine, but now the questions are displayed totaly wrong.

Actually there should be now 3 pages with 3 different questions. On the first page there should be a label with a question"Eine tolle FT Frage?" and below this label an EditText. On the second page there should be a label with a question "Eine tolle SC Frage?" and below a list with the answering options. On page three the should have the question "Eine tolle MC Frage?" and also a list below it with the same answering options as on page two.

The screenshos show a transition between the pages in the order: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2.

you can see, that it does not appear in a way i described it above. the content of the pages does also change during the transition. i believe that there could be a problem with the DummyContent because it's static?!

[image: first page]
[image: second page]
[image: third page]
[image: back to second page, now a question text appears]
[image: back to first page, now there is no question text any more]
[image: back to second page, again another question text appears]

If i create a survey with just one question, everything works fine...

Comment: Where questions displays totaly wrong? Could you add more details?

Comment: I've updated the description above, have a look at the part directly on top of the screenshots.

Comment: Better create three fragments here:  
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    }

Comment: I think i do this already? Becaus in 
public Fragment getItem(int position) i call 
return QuestionFragment.newInstance(questions.get(position));

or am i wrong with this?

Comment: Sorry,its doest matter. i am wrong about three fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i've found the answer:

i wanted to initialize the used widgets in the onCreateView Callback. But then i always got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created". A closer look showed, that this was just because of the getListView() method.

Now i switched the initialization of the widgets to the onCreateView() Callback but the getListView() i left in onActivityCreated().

Now everything works fine, and the fragments are displayed correctly!
That's how it looks right now:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_question, null);

        lblQuestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblQuestion);
        txtAnswer = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        listAnswers = getListView();
        setCorrectLayout();
        initContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener to your indicator.And send BroadCast inside for current page.

```
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int page) {
            switch (page) {
            case 0:
                sendBroadcast(intent)// update your content.When broadcast come set correct layout.
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
```

Implement broadcast listener to the fragment.

Move your  init methods(initWidgets(),initContent())
 to a OnCreateView method

It should works

Comment: thanks for ure response. i tried to put the initWidgets and initContent methods to the onCreateView method. but then i always get an "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created".
I found the solution for my problem... i post it as the answer...